# Like an object on Facebook outside Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've been trying to use the Like button generator to get a Like button for some content on my fan page: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=363385833679921&set=a.314588171893021.85085.305618229456682&type=1

What I want to do is show the likes this photo got on Facebook in the like button on my site and vice versa.

This seems to work for the actual fan page url but doesn't work for individual photos (haven't tested other objects).

You are able to see the likes the object on Facebook got through the graph API call: http://graph.facebook.com/363385833679921. So shouldn't that be available on non-Facebook sites as well?

Anyone know a solution to this without having to make a custom handler to show and post likes on site?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the API to read the comments and likes on the object? Any user's access token will work if that user can see the object

Comment: Yes that is what I did eventually. That information is available in the object's feed.